# hide/display of tag on mouse highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using IE 8

```html
<html>
    <script>
        function xxx(field) {

            if (field.value <= 1) {
                document.getElementById("result").style.display="none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").style.display="display";
            }

        }
    </script>   
    <body>
        AGE
        <input id='numberOfChildren' type='text' onkeypress="xxx(this); "onkeyup="xxx(this); "onkeydown="xxx(this);"/>
        <br />
        <div id="result">PASS</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly for key events, but when I highlight the whole text inside my field and instead of deleting or backspacing I just overwrite the higlighted text, this code fails - it does not hide/display.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with only keyup event

```
<script>
    function xxx(field) {

        if (field.value <= 1) {
            document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("result").style.display = "";
        }

    }
</script>

<body>
    AGE
    <input id='numberOfChildren' type='text'  onkeyup="xxx(this);"
          />
    <br />
    <div id="result">
        PASS</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
document.getElementById("result").style.display="display";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("result").style.display="block";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHNRq/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery use this

```
if(field.value <=1)
 {
  $('#result').hide()
  }
  else
  {
   $('#result').show()
  }
```